# Get query url on PHP

Tags: php, url, curl

I have this url `http://www.mywebsite.com/code.php?number=1234233566456766` or 
`http://www.mywebsite.com/code.php?1234233566456766` if first example is not possible,
and i try to get the code number on `<input type="text" value="<?php get_textafternumber ?>">`
it is possibile?

Comment: What text after what number?

Comment: ?number-->after->1234233566456766

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: how to parse my url? sorry

Comment: Those blue texts are links. You may want to click on them

Answer (score 1):

```
//first, check number through GET
if(isset($_GET['number'])){
 $text = $_GET['number'];
}else{
 //second, check REQUEST_URI
 $urlparts = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 $text = $urlparts['query'];
}
echo $text;
```

Comment: This is assuming that the OP is not simply dealing with a string that happens to be a URL. It could be a string held in a DB.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`parse_url()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). It takes a URL as the input and returns an array containing all of the separate parts.

A slightly altered example from the documentation:

```
$url = 'http://username:password@example.com/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r( parse_url( $url ) );
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => example.com
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```

I believe you are looking for the `query` part of the URL. From there you could possibly use the [`parse_str()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to split that string into variables.